# MongoDB Python MongoEngine - Returning Document by filter of Embedded Documents Sum of Filtered property

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using Python and MongoEngine to try and query the below Document in MongoDB.

I need a query to efficiently get the Documents only when they contain Embedded Documents 'Keywords' that match the following criteria:

- Keywords Filtered where the Property 'SFR' is LTE '100000'
- SUM the filtered keywords
- Return the parent documents where SUM of the keywords matching the criteria is Greater than '9'

**Example structure:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eae60e4055ef0e717f06a50"), 
    "registered_data" : ISODate("2020-05-03T16:12:51.999+0000"), 
    "UniqueName" : "SomeUniqueNameHere", 
    "keywords" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "carport", 
            "search_volume" : NumberInt(10532), 
            "sfr" : NumberInt(20127), 
            "percent_contribution" : 6.47, 
            "competing_product_count" : NumberInt(997), 
            "avg_review_count" : NumberInt(143), 
            "avg_review_score" : 4.05, 
            "avg_price" : 331.77, 
            "exact_ppc_bid" : 3.44, 
            "broad_ppc_bid" : 2.98, 
            "exact_hsa_bid" : 8.33, 
            "broad_hsa_bid" : 9.29
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "party tent", 
            "search_volume" : NumberInt(6944), 
            "sfr" : NumberInt(35970), 
            "percent_contribution" : 4.27, 
            "competing_product_count" : NumberInt(2000), 
            "avg_review_count" : NumberInt(216), 
            "avg_review_score" : 3.72, 
            "avg_price" : 210.16, 
            "exact_ppc_bid" : 1.13, 
            "broad_ppc_bid" : 0.55, 
            "exact_hsa_bid" : 9.66, 
            "broad_hsa_bid" : 8.29
        }
    ]
}
```

From the research I have been doing, I believe an Aggregate type query might do what I am attempting.

Unfortunately, being new to MongoDB / MongoEngine I am struggling to figure out how to structure the query and have failed in finding an example similar to what I am attempting to do (RED FLAG RIGHT????).

I did find an example of a aggregate but unsure how to structure my criteria in it, maybe something like this is getting close but does not work.

```
pipeline = [
    { 
        "$lte": {
            "$sum" : {
                "keywords" : {
                    "$lte": {
                        "keyword": 100000
                    }
                }
            }: 9
        }
    }
]
data = product.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: { // the first project to filter the keywords array
      registered_data: 1,
      UniqueName: 1,
      keywords: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$keywords",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $lte: [
              "$$item.sfr",
              100000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // the second project to get the length of the keywords array
      registered_data: 1,
      UniqueName: 1,
      keywords: 1,
      keywordsLength: {
        $size: "$keywords"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { // then do the match
      keywordsLength: {
        $gte: 9
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vrupCjX61Uk)

hope it helps

> Note, I used `sfr` property only from the keywords array for simplicity